# Does index help a sql select sorting performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "table1" WHERE "id" In('1', '2', '3') ORDER BY "createdAt"
```

I think the benefit for indexing 'createdAt' column is quite minimal, since it does the select first then sort 3 rows. Am I correct? Or it's better to add indexing?

Comment: What do you mean by adding indexing?

Comment: If the number of rows is small an index will not be of use. The query planner will make this decision.

Comment: If `id` is unique, then you are right. Sorting at most three rows is extremely cheap and it's very unlikely that the optimizer would consider the index to help sorting.

Comment: If the data in the table is not too big and the number of ids to be searched is not too large, it will not be necessary to add an index for "createdAt". For id it makes sense to add if the table is too big.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible indexing strategies for the query you show:

1. Index the `IN` condition:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON table1 (id);
   ```

   That is a good idea if the condition is selective, that is, if few table rows match the condition.
2. Index the `ORDER BY` clause:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON table1 ("createdAt");
   ```

   Then the database can scan the index to get the result rows in `ORDER BY` order without an explicit sort.

   This will only be beneficial if the `IN` condition is not selective, that is, most table rows meet the condition.

   Still, depending on the row size and other parameters, PostgreSQL may choose to use a sequential scan and an explicit sort unless you limit the number of result rows with a `LIMIT` clause.

Unfortunately it is not possible to have an index support both the `IN` condition and the `ORDER BY` – that would only be possible if the `WHERE` condition were a plain equality comparison.